# Django 404 Error page not found...the current path matched the last one

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I'm new to django and I'm playing around with my own variation of the polls tutorial. My app was working fine, every page loaded correctly. Then I made a single change; I created and then deleted a model. Now, many of urls seem broken. And I don't understand this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/pick/
Raised by:  polls.views.pick
Using the URLconf defined in mySite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/ [name='index']
polls/ <int:pk>/ [name='detail']
polls/ <int:pk>/results/ [name='results']
polls/ <int:question_id>/vote/ [name='vote']
polls/ <int:question_id>/tally/ [name='tally']
polls/ <int:question_id>/pick/ [name='pick']
The current path, polls/1/pick/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

So I don't understand why it says both that: **The current path, polls/1/pick/, matched the last one.**

and also page not found? How does that work? And what could have caused this when the app was working fine previously?

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('<int:question_id>/tally/', views.tally, name='tally'),
    path('<int:question_id>/pick/', views.pick, name='pick'),
    path('<int:pk>/video/', views.VideoView.as_view(), name='video'),
    path('<int:pk>/reveal/', views.RevealView.as_view(), name='reveal'),
]
```

And views snippit:

```
def pick(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=1)
    question.score = player.score
    question.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:video', args=(question.id,)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line of the error

```
Raised by:  polls.views.pick
```

Is telling you that you didn't get a 404 due to not finding a matching URL, you got a 404 because your view function `polls.views.pick` raised a 404. You have two lines in that function that could raise a 404

```
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=1)
```

So in your database, you either don't have a Question with pk=1 or you don't have a Player with pk=1.

Comment: Could it be something else? Because I do have both of those...and it was working fine before. There other functions acting strangely too that originally worked fine. The problem occurred when I created a new class in my models that was entirely unrelated...and then removed it.

Comment: Okay...now that I checked again somewhere along the way a player object did get deleted. Not sure how but you were right thank you!